# How to get grandTotal in magento 2.3.3?

Tags: magento, return-value, payment-gateway

I'm using magento 2.3.3 and I'm trying to create Custom Payment Gateway. The problem occured when I'm trying to get grandTotal value from `cart` or from `total`. I tried a lot and different codes. Can someone help me with this? As an example I will show some of solutions I've tried.

`$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
 $grandTotal = $cart->getGrandTotal();`

This code returns NULL as everything else. Any help will be appreciated.

I've created controller file that redirects customer to the payment gateway form. It works fine. But I have to send amount. Here is part of code.

```
 public function execute(){
 $back_url = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('tarlanpay/redirect/callback');
    $store_id = $this->getStoreId();
    $order_id = $this->_checkoutSession->getData('last_order_id'); 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
    $grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
    $test_mode = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/tarlanpay/test_mode', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $merchant_id = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/tarlanpay/merchant_id', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $encrypted_key = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/tarlanpay/secret_key', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $secret_key = $this->_encryptor->decrypt($encrypted_key);
    // var_dump($grandTotal) ;die(); // it is debugging

    $post_data = [
            'reference_id' => $store_id.'-'.$order_id,
            'amount' => $grandTotal,
            'description' => 'magento 2',
            'merchant_id' => $merchant_id,
            'secret_key' => $secret_key,
            'is_test' => $test_mode,
            'back_url' => $back_url,
            'request_url' => 'http://magento2'
    ];
   $post_data['secret_key'] = password_hash($store_id.'-'.$order_id.$secret_key, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);

    $ctp_url = 'there is an API.examlpe.com';

    $curl = curl_init($ctp_url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
     'Accept: application/json'
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    $decoded_response = json_decode($response, true);

    $form_action_url = $decoded_response['data']['redirect_url']; //it's an info that came from payment gateway
    $array_data = array (
    'action' =>$form_action_url,
    'fields' => 'success'
    );
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    return $result->setData($array_data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
 public function execute(){
 $back_url = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('tarlanpay/redirect/callback');
    $store_id = $this->getStoreId();
    $order_id = $this->_checkoutSession->getData('last_order_id'); 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->load($order_id);
    $grandTotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
    $test_mode = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/tarlanpay/test_mode', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $merchant_id = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/tarlanpay/merchant_id', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $encrypted_key = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('payment/tarlanpay/secret_key', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $secret_key = $this->_encryptor->decrypt($encrypted_key);
    // var_dump($grandTotal) ;die(); // it is debugging

    $post_data = [
            'reference_id' => $store_id.'-'.$order_id,
            'amount' => $grandTotal,
            'description' => 'magento 2',
            'merchant_id' => $merchant_id,
            'secret_key' => $secret_key,
            'is_test' => $test_mode,
            'back_url' => $back_url,
            'request_url' => 'http://magento2'
    ];
   $post_data['secret_key'] = password_hash($store_id.'-'.$order_id.$secret_key, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 10]);

    $ctp_url = 'there is an API.examlpe.com';

    $curl = curl_init($ctp_url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
     'Accept: application/json'
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    $decoded_response = json_decode($response, true);

    $form_action_url = $decoded_response['data']['redirect_url']; //it's an info that came from payment gateway
    $array_data = array (
    'action' =>$form_action_url,
    'fields' => 'success'
    );
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    return $result->setData($array_data);
}
```

Comment: It returns NULL as well. I found one interesting thing. When I click "place order" button in shows NULL, but when I parallelly open second page and add product to the cart (in second page) and refresh first page, it shows me amount (in first page). It means that when I trigger "place order" button in cleans shopping cart. How to disable that?

Comment: May I know how you create custom payment gateway?

Comment: I've edited my question. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please check my answer I have updated it.If it solved your problem please accept it.

Comment: Your answer totally correct! Just try to remove `echo` here-> ` $grandTotal = echo $order->getGrandTotal();` Everything works correctly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204763/discussion-between-jinesh-and-thelucker777).